# Can a public method of a public class be called in the main by just its name like "method()" in place of "classname.method()"?

Tags: java

I came across this code in hackerrank.com which made me ask this question:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {


    static int solveMeFirst(int a, int b) {
        return a+b;
   }


 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a;
        a = in.nextInt();
        int b;
        b = in.nextInt();
        int sum;
        sum = solveMeFirst(a, b);
        System.out.println(sum);
   }
}
```

why is this possible?
Here, shouldn't it be Solution.solveMeFirst(a,b);

Comment: Do you add the full address of your house if you tell someone that you're going into the bath/kitchen/any other room? Since you're currently in your house, the context is clear and you don't have to add the address. If you like go into a room of another house, then you need to add the address or else no one will know which room you mean. Java behaves the same like this.

Answer (score 2):

> Here, shouldn't it be Solution.solveMeFirst(a,b);

You *could* call it that, but you certainly don't have to.

The detailed rules for finding the meaning of a name are given in [JLS 6.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5), but basically the compiler will search through the "current" class (the one that you're calling it from) and all ancestor classes (in this case just `Object`). It will also use any static imports (which you don't have in this case).

It's just the same with instance methods:

```
public class Foo {
    public void firstMethod() {
        secondMethod();
    }

    private void secondMethod() {
    }
}
```

An instance method can call a static method without any qualification, but a static method *can't* call an instance method without specifying the instance on which to call the method, e.g.

```
public class Foo {
    public static void staticMethod(Foo instance) {
        instance.instanceMethod();
    }

    private void instanceMethod() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible because you are inside the class with the static method you like to invoke.
It is not a special behaviour of the main method.
Any static method can be invoked from the same class both from another static method (like main) but also from a non static method.